# Classic ASP Loop Through XML

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have a XML payload as follows

```
<tsResponse>
 <sites>
  <site id="site-id"  name="site1-name" contentUrl="site1-content-url"  /> 
   <projects>
    <project id="project1-id" name="project1-name"/>
    <project id="project2-id" name="project2-name"/>
   </projects>
  </site>
  <site id="site2-id" name="site2-name" contentUrl="site2-content-url" /> 
   <projects>
    <project id="project3-id" name="project3-name"/>
    <project id="project4-id" name="project4-name"/>
   </projects>
  </site>
 </sites>
</tsResponse>
```

I can loop through each site, collecting each site ID, name and contentURL as I go along with the following

```
    Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    oXML.LoadXML(postResponse) ' sXML is a variable containing the content of your XML file

    For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("/tsResponse/sites/site")
        sID = oNode.GetAttribute("id")
        sName = oNode.GetAttribute("name")
        sContentURL = oNode.GetAttribute("contentUrl")
    Next
    Set oXML = Nothing
```

However how do I pick up each project ID and name within each site? Would I need another For Loop within the existing one or is that too inefficient? How do I loop through where a particular attribute = X?

**UPDATE**

```
For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("/tsResponse/sites/site")
  sID = oNode.GetAttribute("id")
  sName = oNode.GetAttribute("name")
  sContentURL = oNode.GetAttribute("contentUrl")
  Response.write("<h2>"&sName&" / "&sID&" / "&sContentURL&"</h2>")
  For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("/tsResponse/sites/site[@id='"&sID&"']/projects/project")
    pID = oNode.GetAttribute("id")
    pName = oNode.GetAttribute("name")
    Response.write("<h3>"&pID&" / "&pName&"</h3>")
  Next
Next
Set oXML = Nothing
```

On the second `For loop` I get `Invalid 'for' loop control variable`

Changed oNode to oNode2 and it works!

Comment: Does that work? You're missing the `projects` node from your `SelectNodes` method in the `For` loop...

Comment: This works to get the sites but I want sites and then all projects for each site. Making amend to question

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("/tsResponse/sites/site")
  sID = oNode.GetAttribute("id")
  sName = oNode.GetAttribute("name")
  sContentURL = oNode.GetAttribute("contentUrl")
  Response.write("<h2>"&sName&" / "&sID&" / "&sContentURL&"</h2>")
  For Each oNode2 In oXML.SelectNodes("/tsResponse/sites/site[@id='"&sID&"']/projects/project")
    pID = oNode2.GetAttribute("id")
    pName = oNode2.GetAttribute("name")
    Response.write("<h3>"&pID&" / "&pName&"</h3>")
  Next
Next
Set oXML = Nothing
```

Comment: You can't re-use `oNode` it's already a loop control variable, give it a different name.